# conditioning with vectors

Tags: r

I'm new to r.

I have a vector (of length 100) of ordered pairs.  I also have a vector (also of length 100) of 1's and 0's. I'd like to "reverse" the ordered pairs whenever the other vector has a 1 in the same position and leave it un-reversed when there's a 0.  I've tried (naively and hopelessly)

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  if (flip[i]=1) {
    pair[i,] = rev(pair[i,])
  } else {
    pair[i,] = pair[i,]
  }
}
```

I've also tried this with a variety of brackets around statements

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `flip` and `pair`?

Comment: flip=sample(c(0,1), 100, replace=TRUE)

Comment: oops...I'm new to this site too.

Comment: pair=array(1:200, dim=c(100,2))

Comment: it would be best if you edit those into your original question.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't work because `=` is used for assignment and `==` is used for logical comparison.  This works:

```
flip = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace=TRUE)
pair = array(1:200, dim=c(100,2))

for (i in 1:100) {
  if (flip[i]==1) {
    pair[i,] = rev(pair[i,])
  } else {
    pair[i,] = pair[i,]
  }
}
```

That said, there are handy vectorized solutions to this type of problem (as @Prasad has demonstrated).

Answer (score 3):

Take a small example:

```
pair <- matrix(1:10,5,2)
flip <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
> pair
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
```

Then you can flip the desired rows of `pair` using:

```
pair[flip==1,] <-  pair[ flip == 1, 2:1 ]

> pair
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    1
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    9    4
[5,]    5   10
```

Comment: Thank you, hey what is the significance of 2:1 in the condition?

Comment: The expression 2:1 is just the sequence 2 to 1, i.e. c(2,1).

Comment: @mike, it is the flipping. `2:1` selects column 2 and 1 in that order, so the result is the flipped original.

Comment: @mike you're welcome. The syntax `pairs[ flip == 1, 2:1 ]` does two things: it picks out the rows for which `flip == 1`, and for those rows, it extracts the columns in the sequence specified by `2:1`, i.e. the second column, then the first column -- which is exactly what you need to do to reverse the pairs in each row.